# PostgreSQL: How to figure out missing numbers in a column using generate_series()?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4, generate-series

```
SELECT commandid 
FROM results 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM generate_series(0,119999) 
    WHERE generate_series = results.commandid 
    );
```

I have a column in `results` of type `int` but various tests failed and were not added to the table.  I would like to create a query that returns a list of `commandid` that are not found in `results`.  I thought the above query would do what I wanted. However, it does not even work if I use a range that is outside the expected possible range of `commandid` (like negative numbers).

Comment: You can't return a value from a column, if that value does not exist in the table. The query must be written from the reverse perspective.

Comment: PostgreSQL version? Schema? Sample data?

Comment: Your query doesn't even parse.

Comment: Craig, you are correct.  I was trying to type it from memory when I should have just copy/pasted it.

Comment: @sunnyohno Thanks for the fix. BTW, it's best to mention your Pg version in any question, so people know if they can use (say) window functions, unnest(), or various other features not in old versions in answers. It can also help explain unexpected behaviour sometimes.

Comment: I have added the version#, 8.4.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Given sample data:

```
create table results ( commandid integer primary key);
insert into results (commandid) select * from generate_series(1,1000);
delete from results where random() < 0.20;
```

This works:

```
SELECT s.i AS missing_cmd
FROM generate_series(0,1000) s(i)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM results WHERE commandid = s.i);
```

as does this alternative formulation:

```
SELECT s.i AS missing_cmd
FROM generate_series(0,1000) s(i)
LEFT OUTER JOIN results ON (results.commandid = s.i) 
WHERE results.commandid IS NULL;
```

Both of the above appear to result in identical query plans in my tests, but you should compare with your data on your database using `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to see which is best.

### Explanation

Note that instead of `NOT IN` I've used `NOT EXISTS` with a subquery in one formulation, and an ordinary `OUTER JOIN` in the other. It's much easier for the DB server to optimise these and it avoids the confusing issues that can arise with `NULL`s in `NOT IN`.

I initially favoured the `OUTER JOIN` formulation, but at least in 9.1 with my test data the `NOT EXISTS` form optimizes to the same plan.

Both will perform better than the `NOT IN` formulation below when the series is large, as in your case. `NOT IN` used to require Pg to do a linear search of the `IN` list for every tuple being tested, but examination of the query plan suggests Pg may be smart enough to hash it now. The `NOT EXISTS` (transformed into a `JOIN` by the query planner) and the `JOIN` work better.

The `NOT IN` formulation is both confusing in the presence of NULL `commandid`s and can be inefficient:

```
SELECT s.i AS missing_cmd
FROM generate_series(0,1000) s(i)
WHERE s.i NOT IN (SELECT commandid FROM results);
```

so I'd avoid it. With 1,000,000 rows the other two completed in 1.2 seconds and the `NOT IN` formulation ran CPU-bound until I got bored and cancelled it.

Comment: this is a great explanation.  unfortunately, for people saying "redshift is postgresql" like I did today, we'll quickly discover that aws redshift doesn't support generate_series

Comment: @JohnHaugeland Yeah. Redshift isn't PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 9):

As I mentioned in the comment, you need to do the reverse of the above query.

```
SELECT
    generate_series
FROM
    generate_series(0, 119999)
WHERE
    NOT generate_series IN (SELECT commandid FROM results);
```

At that point, you should find values that do not exist within the `commandid` column within the selected range.

Comment: If `commandid` can ever be `NULL`, results will not be what you expect. Probably not an issue in this case, but worth bearing in mind.

Comment: Good point. @sunnyohno If that's an issue, add in a `WHERE commandid IS NOT NULL` into the subquery.

Comment: Pickypg, thank you very much for this answer but I am giving the correct answer to Mr. Ringer since it takes into consideration the size of my data.

Comment: Fine by me. The point of SO is to get the best answer, and not necessarily the first one.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I also had in mind (but wasn't sure on how to do it). But comparing this solution to Craig's it is much slower on a table of 10.000.000 entries to find the missing ones on  a range of 100 or so. But, +1

Answer (score 0):

I am not so experienced SQL guru, but I like other ways to solve problem.
Just today I had similar problem - to find unused numbers in one character column.
I have solved my problem by using pl/pgsql and was very interested in what will be speed of my procedure.
I used @Craig Ringer's way to generate table with serial column, add one million records, and then delete every 99th record. This procedure work about 3 sec in searching for missing numbers:

```
-- creating table
create table results (commandid character(7) primary key);
-- populating table with serial numbers formatted as characters
insert into results (commandid) select cast(num_id as character(7)) from generate_series(1,1000000) as num_id;
-- delete some records
delete from results where cast(commandid as integer) % 99 = 0;

create or replace function unused_numbers()
  returns setof integer as
$body$
declare
   i integer;
   r record;
begin
   -- looping trough table with sychronized counter:
   i := 1;
   for r in
      (select distinct cast(commandid as integer) as num_value
      from results
      order by num_value asc)
   loop
      if not (i = r.num_value) then
            while true loop
               return next i;

               i = i + 1;
               if (i = r.num_value) then
                     i = i + 1;
                     exit;
                  else
                     continue;
               end if;
            end loop;
         else
            i := i + 1;
      end if;
   end loop;

   return;
end;
$body$
  language plpgsql volatile
  cost 100
  rows 1000;

select * from unused_numbers();
```

Maybe it will be usable for someone.

Answer (score -1):

If you're on AWS redshift, you might end up needing to defy the question, since it doesn't support `generate_series`.  You'll end up with something like this:

```
select 
    startpoints.id    gapstart, 
    min(endpoints.id) resume 
from (
     select id+1 id 
     from   yourtable outer_series 
     where not exists 
         (select null 
          from   yourtable inner_series 
          where  inner_series.id = outer_series.id + 1
         )
     order by id
     ) startpoints,   

     yourtable endpoints 
where 
    endpoints.id > startpoints.id 
group by 
    startpoints.id;
```