# Postgres Query to find the missing numbers from a certain range

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a field serial no where i am saving sequence no like '201801'. I have records up till '20185600'. Now in between '201801' and  '20185600' some sequence numbers are missed.I want to find those missing numbers with postgres query.Please help me out

Answer (score 2):

Try making use of the range

```
SELECT s.id AS missing_ids
    FROM generate_series(201801, 20185600) s(id)
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE id = s.id);
```

Comment: [Have a look here for better explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444142/postgresql-how-to-figure-out-missing-numbers-in-a-column-using-generate-series)